# Why does ESB application generates warning while trying to fetch "'mule-tracking-ee.xsd'" during deployment?

Tags: mule-esb

I am using Mule ESB 3.8.1 community Edition to create an application. While deploying the application in Mule ESB server, it tries to fetch the above xsd and generates the warning as follows:

```
WARN  2019-08-23 13:36:50,950 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

This happens twice each time the mule service is started and caues delay in deployment. How can this issue be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Schemas (and components) with 'ee' means they are Mule Enterprise Edition (ee) only Features. They are not available in a Community Edition server. Remove the references from the schema and flow and it should deploy. You will not be able to use those feature though.